# Adding item in empty observable collection which bind to combobox lead to auto select this item in combobox, but selected value is still null

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, selectedvalue

I have this throuble:

There observable collection, which bind to combobox. When collection contains any items, all works fine, I add items in collection, then choose him in combobox, selected value is not null.

I have items control,which contains any component controls which reflect any entity. I may select parameter this entity in combobox which bind to observable collection.

If I add first new entity in content control and collection is empty, then add item in collection - this item automaticaly select in combobox, but combobox selected value is null. It turns out, this situation: item select in combobox, but combobox selected value is null. If i select this item manualy, selected value is set to this item and work further аштую I don't understand how it may be.
There is my code:
this is collection

```
public ObservableCollection<AnyType> AnyTemplates { get; set; }
```

this is xaml code combobox:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbKeyA" 
          Width="100" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=KeyAName}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.KeyTemplates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValuePath="Name"/>
```

Comment: I found something else, the problem is that when i change value(which bind to combobox selectedValue property) in collection which bind my combobox - selected item in combobox is changed, but selected value not update until I manually choose this element in combobox. Property which i change send PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand your problem, but from what I do understand I would use either a Dependency Property or a Property that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged event to bind to SelectedItem of the ComboBox. Then when I wanted to add an Item to the ObservableCollection (assuming you want it to be selected), I would both add it to the collection and set my new Property equal to it.

Comment: Sorry if my question turned obscure. I'll try again, I'm dynamicaly add items in Item control. Each Item component. After adding checkbox have SelectedItem and SelectedValue is null. But, when i add new item in observableCollection - that Combobox I have just added set selected item to this new collection element. Then i change Name(this implement Property changed) in this collection element and what i have - combobox selectedItem is this new collection element, but SelectedValue is NULL! Why?